# How do I compress an input into a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been struggling to find a way to compress an input from a user into a .txt file. I need to compress the users input down into the txt file, as well as being able to re-open it with it's original format and capitalization.
The current code I have is:

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT CAN YOU DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
listSentence = sentence.split(" ")
d = {}
i = 0
values = []
for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(" ")):
    if not word in d:
        d[word] = (i+1)
     values += [d[word]]
print(values)
file = open("listofwords.txt","w")
file.write(str(values))
file.close()
```

This code simply assigns values to the words in the sentence and replaces repeated words and writes the sentence to the file.

Comment: Is this the sentence the total of what you are trying to compress?

Comment: If you are creating your own compression algorithm, you might want to read about Huffman code.

Comment: You may want to read also on Python serializing, which might also be applicable (http://tinyurl.com/z62hqxx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Out [zlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html):

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT CAN YOU DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
com = zlib.compress(sentence)
with open("listofwords.txt", "wb") as myfile:
    myfile.write(com)
```

Or for decompress:

```
with open("listofwords.txt", "rb") as myfile:
    com = myfile.read()
sentence = zlib.decompress(com)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this!

Comment: zlib will not always help for short sentences such as this. This one has some repetition so yes it will work.It works well usually for larger blocks.

Comment: @wolfsgang It didnt say anything in documentation , but yeah you right , I didnt found any better library for this

Comment: @wolfsgang, I don't think "short" sentences need to be compressed. Compression was meant for big files. Big enough to statistically accomodate some compression

Comment: @wolfsgang Yeah , I know this , but maybe there is alot of such string that he want to compress them

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of the help, and to Arman for his answer. I also did more looking around and I have found out gzip also is a good way to do this. I have changed the program so it can have two inputs.

```
sentences = input("Enter the text you want to compress: ")
name = input("Please enter your desired file name: ")
with gzip.open(filename + ".gz", "wt") as outfile:
     outfile.write(plaintext)
```